# Difference between percentage points and percent

Tags: definition, percentage

Although I am aware that percentage points should be used to describe arithmetical differences between two percent figures, I could not find a satisfying literature reference. Can anyone recommend an encyclopedia with a definition of percentage points (besides wikipedia, I know the entry)?

Comment: This is not a site where we simply provide mathematical definitions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, why not? We have a tag for `[definition]` w/ 193 threads, & we have a tag for `[references]` w/ 1293. This question seems potentially on topic to me.

Comment: I am just following what Bill Huber commented on a similar thread.

Comment: [Confusion between percentage and percentage point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337984/confusion-between-percentage-and-percentage-point)

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia entry that you mention lists two possible literature references:

- Brechner, Robert (2008). "Contemporary Mathematics for Business and Consumers", Brief Edition. Cengage Learning. p. 190. Retrieved 7 May 2015.
- Wickham, Kathleen (2003). "Math Tools for Journalists." Cengage Learning. p. 30. Retrieved 7 May 2015.